# My More Recent Files On File History Are Gone

Tags: backup, data-recovery, file-history

My computer crashed and I had to eventually reinstall Windows 10 in order to get it working again. I wasn't too worried since I used File History to backup my files.

Unfortunately it seems that only file up until the end of last year are still there. I remember checking recently and it was up to date and backed up once a day. Now the files seem to be gone.

I'm trying to use Recuva to see if I can find them anywhere but it doesn't seem to be helping. Is there any way to find what happened to my backups in File History?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Really you trust Windows with your backup data?

Comment: I had no reason to think it would fail like this. Obviously I'm not going to again.

Comment: @Moab why wouldn't someone trust Windows with their backup data? (genuinely curious as Windows backups came up in discussion recently and I know little about them)

Comment: @bertieb because it is unreliable.